# Php&mysql pagination script for huge website

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, pagination

I have a big database with over 3 million rows and i need a php&mysql pagination script. I already have one but after i pass the level of 1000 pages it's working very slow like minutes to load. Any script/advice that can help me is welcomed.

Edit, im using this script

```
<?php
// Script de paginare, de la http://www.marplo.net

// Datele pt. conectare la baza de date
// MODIFICATI
$host = "localhost";    // server MySQL
$utilizator = "root"; 
$parola = "parola";
$numebd = "nume_bd";    // nume baza de date

// Conectarea la baza de date
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $utilizator, $parola);
if (!$conn) {
  echo 'Conectare nereusita la MySQL'; 
  exit;
}

// Selectarea bazei de date
if (!mysql_select_db($numebd, $conn)) {
  echo 'Baza de date nu a putut fi selectata deoarece : '. mysql_error();
  exit;
}

// Setarea pentru format UTF-8
$sql = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
mysql_query($sql, $conn);

// Afla cate linii sunt in tabel (MODIFICATI 'nume_tb') din baza de date  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `nume_tb`";  
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error(E_USER_ERROR);  
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);  
$numrows = $r[0];  

// Stabileste numarul de linii din tabel afisate in pagina 
$rowsperpage = 10;  
// afla numarul total necesar de pagini 
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);        // ceil face rotunjire la int. maxim

// Obtine pagina curenta sau seteaza default 
if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {  
  // seteaza variabila ca int 
  $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];  
} else {  
  // pagina care este initial afisata (pagina default) 
  $currentpage = 1;  
}

// daca pagina curenta e mai mare decat total pagini...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {  
  // seteaza pagina curenta la ultima pagina  
  $currentpage = $totalpages;  
} 
// daca pagina curenta e mai mica decat prima pagina...  
if ($currentpage < 1) {  
  // seteaza pagina curenta la prima pagina   
  $currentpage = 1;  
} 

// lista cu pagini, in functie de pagina curenta   
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;  

// obtine datele din tabel (MODIFICATI 'nume_tb') din baza de date  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `nume_tb` LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";  
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error(E_USER_ERROR);  

// parcurgerea matricei cu datele obtinute 
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
  // - MODIFICATI numele coloanelor tabelului ('id' si 'texte')
  // Stocheaza datele returnate de MySQL in variabile array pt. fiecare coloana
  $id[] = $list['id'];
  $text[] = $list['texte'];
}
mysql_close();  // Incheie conexiunea cu mysql

/*** Afisarea datelor obtinute ***/
// Parcurge variabilele array setate in bucla WHILE
for($i=0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
  // Aici puteti adauga cod HTML pentru aspectul grafic al afisarii
  echo $id[$i]. " - ". $text[$i]. "<br />";
}

/*** Construirea link-urilor pt. paginare ***/ 
// raza nr. link-uri din jurul celui curent 
$range = 3;

// Link-uri inapoi, daca pagina curenta nu e prima
if ($currentpage > 1) {  
  // arata << pt. link la prima pagina  
  echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'>&lt;&lt;</a> &nbsp; ";  
  // obtine nr. pagina din urma 
  $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;  
  // arata < pt. link la o pagina in urma 
  echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>&lt;</a> &nbsp;";  
} 

// definirea link-urilor din raza paginii curente
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {  
  // daca e un nr. de pagina valid ... 
  if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {  
     // daca nr. e pagina curenta ...  
     if ($x == $currentpage) {  
        // afiseaza nr. pagina fara a fi link  
        echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";  
     // daca nr. nu e pagina curenta ...  
     } else {  
        // il face link  
    echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";  
     }  
  }
}

// Daca pagina curenta nu e ultima, afiseaza link inainte si spre ultima pagina
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {  
  // obtine pagina urmatoare 
  $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;  
   // arata > pt. urmatoarea pagina   
  echo "&nbsp; <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>&gt;</a> ";  
  //  arata >> pt. ultima pagina
  echo " &nbsp; <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>&gt;&gt;</a> ";  
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ and you find the search box on the top-right corner.

Comment: Actually its a good questions.

Comment: I'd argue you need to think about your use case. Look at Google it's search results on "test" end after 830 results.  

My point is simply that when you hit 1,000 pages  tell the user to refine their results... if someone literally looks through  1,000 pages, that's simply bad business.

Comment: Im not using this as a search results page. I want to have my pages indexed easier.

Comment: Do you have any search criteria that can help narrow down the results that are displayed? The problem is that MySQL has to generate the query results every time you make that query, in order to get the entries that are within the specified `LIMIT` range. If you can reduce the overall size of the result set, it will speed up the time it takes to generate it. If you can't do any sort of narrowing, your only real path is to start caching the results, and using the cached results instead so that it isn't being regenerated every time you make the query.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the search function and the related questions widget before you post a new question next time.

The large LIMIT problem :

> Beware of large LIMIT Using index to sort is efficient if you need first few rows, even if some extra filtering takes place so you need to scan more rows by index then requested by LIMIT. However if you're dealing with LIMIT query with large offset efficiency will suffer. LIMIT 1000,10 is likely to be way slower than LIMIT 0,10. It is true most users will not go further than 10 page in results, however Search Engine Bots may very well do so. I've seen bots looking at 200+ page in my projects. Also for many web sites failing to take care of this provides very easy task to launch a DOS attack - request page with some large number from few connections and it is enough. If you do not do anything else make sure you block requests with too large page numbers.
>
> For some cases, for example if results are static it may make sense to precompute results so you can query them for positions.
>   So instead of query with LIMIT 1000,10 you will have WHERE position between 1000 and 1009 which has same efficiency for any position (as long as it is indexed)

[ORDER BY … LIMIT Performance Optimization](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/)

Related Question:
[Alphabetical pagination gets progressively slower as you page (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686986/alphabetical-pagination-gets-progressively-slower-as-you-page-mysql)

Comment: While this is something that he should keep in mind, it's not strictly related to `LIMIT`; the problem is in the size of the data set that has to be looked through to generate the results. For paging, `LIMIT` works fine, and is really the best way to do it.

If efficiency is an issue, narrower search criteria should be applied. Any possible method that dynamically pulls a range of data entries is going to encounter exactly the same issues that `LIMIT` has, because it has to generate the entire result set up to the end of the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MySQL, you can take advantage of the `LIMIT` command:

```
$start = ($current_page - 1) * $rows_per_page; //Entry 1 on page 1 is index 0
$select = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT $start, $rows_per_page"
```

Comment: Fun fact: He didn't have that code listed when I posted this.

Comment: Sorry bro no offense, but i cannot remove my downvote until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

A few minor things:

- You seem to only be using 'id' and 'texte' from each row.  Using a `SELECT *` in this case is fine if these are the only two columns, but it's wasteful if there are other columns.  Use `SELECT id,texte` instead, if that's the case.
- You can get rid of the intermediate variable $list by doing `while (list(id[],text[]) = mysql_fetch_row());` (provided your rows have id and texte as the first two columns, or you change your `SELECT` as per my previous bullet point).  Similarly for retrieving the row count: `list($numrows) = mysql_fetch_row($result);` will work.
- You can delete `{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}` from all of your hrefs.  "?currentpage=6" is a perfectly valid (relative) href.  For shorter html, consider using 'p' instead of 'currentpage' as the querystring variable.

---

Now a couple of more major ones:

---

(1) The speed issue is definitely a MySQL problem from what I can see - there are no large loops in your code.

Try (a) making 'id' a primary key (if it isn't already; or just make it an index if you already have another primary key column), and (b) adding an `ORDER BY id` clause to the select statement that fetches the data.  That should definitely help.

If it doesn't, *as a last resort* you could then create a second table to index your rows:

```
CREATE TABLE nume_tb_idx (
  idx int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES nume_tb (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

(assuming here your id column is an int).

You'll have to add an entry to this table when you add a row to nume_tb, and *re-number* the later entries after deleting a row from nume_tb (you could use triggers for that).  The idea is that the values in 'idx' are always consecutive numbers starting from 1, up to the total number of rows in nume_tb.  Then instead of using LIMIT, you'd use the following SELECT statement:

```
"SELECT id,texte FROM nume_tb_idx INNER JOIN nume_tb USING (id)
WHERE idx BETWEEN $offset AND ".$offset+$rowsperpage-1." ORDER BY idx"
```

That should always work very fast.

---

(2) The way you're doing the page navigation links is pretty useless.  For large numbers of pages like you have, an ideal solution would be "logarithmic" page navigation.  For a description and PHP sample code, see my answer to this question:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)